# Multiple HasMany BelongsTo relation on loopback

Tags: node.js, models, loopbackjs, has-many

I've a model called "jornal" with has two belongsTo relation, with models "obra" and "operario". Both of them have a hasMany relation with "jornal" model.

How can I create an instance of "jornal" model related with an "obra" instance and with an "operario" instance?

I've try chain a post to operario/id/jornal POST sending jornal object (without id, because it's a new instance), and then a POST to obra. If I send without id, it creates a new jornal instance, and if I send the whole object returned from previous POST, it says duplicate id.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
POST /jornals
```

with data object

```
{
  "obraId": 1,
  "operarioId": 1
}
```

Set ids to whichever 'obra' and 'operario' objects you wish to relate to.

Comment: I didn't try this. I tried to insert obra object in obra field and the id in obra field, but not the obraId field. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm just started with loopback, but I think HasMany polymorphic relation will help you.

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Polymorphic+relations

Comment: No  jornal belongs to operario AND belongs to obra.